# What HTTP status should I use to send a 404 page?

Tags: node.js, express, http, http-status-code-404, server-side-rendering

I have a single page app in which all the routing is done on the client, using `react-router-dom`.

My app allows a set of exact match routes.

For any route out of that set, it will be considered invalid and the client code will redirect you to the `/404-page` route.

So **I need to do the same when I'm rendering on the server.**

This is the flow:

- You'll ask my server for `/invalid-route`
- My code from `react-router` will render a `<Redirect to="/404-page"/>`
- I will need to redirect your request to `/404-page`
- What code should I use for that redirect?

I guess I should set `status = 404`. Because that route was not found, right?

Something like:

```
// YOU'VE REQUESTED SOME /invalid-route

res.status(404).redirect(ROUTES.NOT_FOUND);
```

But now you gonna ask my server for the `/404-page` route. Which will actually render a `404 Page`

- You ask for `/404-page`
- My server will render a 404 page for you.
- Which status code should I use for the 404 page?

Should I use `200 Ok` ? Since my `/404-page` is a valid and existing URL that will actually render something?

```
// NOW YOU ARE REQUESTING MY /404-page

res.status(200).send( // 404 PAGE HTML );
```

Is this the right way of doing this?

---

**UPDATE:**

My question was assuming something wrong.

When a user asks for a `/invalid-url`, you can't send a `404` and redirect at the same time.

Because the following code:

```
// YOU'VE REQUESTED SOME /invalid-route

res.status(404).redirect(ROUTES.NOT_FOUND);

// NOW YOU ARE REQUESTING MY /404-page

res.status(200).send( // 404 PAGE HTML );
```

Produced the following result:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The redirect was done using `302` even though I was using `res.status(404).`.

This is not intended at all. Because no `404` status was emitted.

So I guess we should redirect `/invalid-route` with `302` or `301`, and send the `404` for the `/404-page`

Something like:

```
// YOU'VE REQUESTED SOME /invalid-route

res.status(302).redirect(ROUTES.NOT_FOUND);

// NOW YOU ARE REQUESTING MY /404-page

res.status(404).send( // 404 PAGE HTML );
```

---

UPDATE 2:

This does not work as intended to send a `301`

```
// THIS SENDS A 302, EVEN THOUGH SETTING 301

res.status(301).redirect(ROUTES.NOT_FOUND);
```

To send a 301 on a redirect, I had to do:

```
// THIS SYNTAX ALLOWS YOU TO CHOOSE THE STATUS CODE FOR THE REDIRECT

res.redirect(301,ROUTES.NOT_FOUND);
``´


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNnfN.png
```

Answer (score 1):

My gut says that a 404 page should always return a 404 status. If it comes with an actual page to display that 404 message, then that's fine. This is what I think is intuitive.

This is my mental picture for this request flow:

1. Client GET /invalid-route -> Server
2. Server 404 `<Redirect to="/404-page"/>` -> Client
3. Client GET /404-page -> Server
4. Server 404 /404-page -> Client

I think the confusion comes from thinking of the 404 page as an existing resource which should return 200 when requested. I prefer to think of the 404 page as less of a page and more of a 404 status code with some human redable html to render the code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if I'm overthinking this. But it feels weird either way. Returning 404 for a page that actually exists, even if it is a 404 page, it doesn't seem right.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details. It seems you can't redirect with `404` at the same response. Either you do one thing or the other.